# Sections in Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reporting

I need create a detailed report with Report Viewer in a Windows Forms app, but I had problems for create nested information. For example:

Section 1 - Customer Info
      Customer details with table and other data
Section 2 - Other related structured data
      Data section 1
            Data section body
      Data section 2
            Data section body
      ...
      Data section X
...
Section Y - Other info
      ...

I only find to show a table related to just one Object or Dataset. How I can manage sections or more complex tables, maybe like Crystal Reports?

Comment: Please provide more details to your question. What type of reportin tool you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But it sounds like you need to insert crosstabs or subreports. Both are very well supported in Crystal Reports and can render data outside the grouping/sorting structure of the main report.

Comment: The matter is if I can do this with Report Viewer?